# Multiple expandable listView in Android React Native

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, expandablelistview

I am trying to build a feature in react native android where we have multiple nested expandable listview.

For eg:

```
  --> Question1
         -->subquestion1
                 -->answer1
                 -->answer2
         --> subquestion2
  -->Question2
```

When user click on question, it will expand to show list of sub questions and when one of the sub question is clicked it will expand to show the answer of the sub-question.

Please help me to build this feature in react-native android.

Comment: Try using react native treeview https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-treeview

Answer (score 0):

**Use Panels:** https://github.com/crysfel/Panels

Support for both Android & iOS

**Tutorial:** https://moduscreate.com/expanding-and-collapsing-elements-using-animations-in-react-native/

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Demo:** https://github.com/hiteshsahu/ReactNative-Expandable-List-View

Answer (score -1):

An extendable, flexible ExpandableListView or [ExpandableLayout](https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout) widget that supports animations.

Here is a video of the example, showcasing the robustness of the widget: [click here sample code on github](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView)

Comment: I want it in react-native